# Программа-сервер на java использует много памяти при отправке картинки на клиент

Tags: java, android, сервер, изображения, память

Пишу простенький чат. Сервер написан с использованием Spark Framework. Запросы с андроида делаю с использованием Retrofit2. Решил взяться за отправку картинок в сообщении,  сразу же появилась проблема. Когда телефон делает запрос на загрузку фотки, сервер начинает жрать просто огромное количество ОЗУ. При загрузке 5 фоток весом до 1МБ сервер жрёт около 100МБ. И ладно бы после этого он освобождал память, но нет, не освобождает. При каждой загрузке фотки используется всё больше и больше памяти, пока не вылетает программа из за нехватки памяти.
Мне хочется узнать из за чего оно жрёт так много памяти и можно ли это как то оптимизировать.

Обработчик запроса на сервере:

```
get("/loadImage", (request, response) -> {
        DBController dbController = new DBController();
        QueryParamsMap map = request.queryMap();

        String note = map.value("note");
        int messageId = Integer.valueOf(map.value("messageId"));

        return dbController.loadImage(note, messageId);
    },new JsonTransformer());
```

Преобразование результата в JSON:

```
public class JsonTransformer implements ResponseTransformer {

private Gson gson = new Gson();

@Override
public String render(Object model) {
    return gson.toJson(model);
}
```

Получение картинки из базы:

```
public byte[] loadImage(String note, int messageId){
    String selectImage = String.format("select image from notes.%s where num=%d", note, messageId);
    byte[] image = null;
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectImage);
        resultSet.next();
        image = resultSet.getBytes("image");
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Создание запроса на телефоне:

```
private void loadAndSaveImageFromServer(final Message message) {
    final int messageId = message.getMessageId();

    RestService gitHubService = RestService.retrofit.create(RestService.class);

    final Call<byte[]> call =
            gitHubService.loadImage(numberOfNote, messageId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<byte[]> call, Response<byte[]> response) {
            if(response.body() != null){
                byte[] image = response.body();
                message.setImage(image);

                try {
                    saveImage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                NoteDBHelper helper = new NoteDBHelper(getContext(), numberOfNote);
                helper.updateImagePath(numberOfNote, messageId, message.getImagePath());

                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<byte[]> call, Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А клиент в чем виноват, что сервер память жрет?

Comment: Нужно проанализировать дамп памяти при помощи MAT.

Comment: @talex MAT это что то из Eclipse?